# How to send a message when a webpage text with Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, telegram

How to send a message when a webpage text with Selenium in Python?

Hello, I am a python beginner.
I want to send a message with telegram in Python. 
I got a text to send message from webpage.
How can I send a telegram message?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import telegram

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "http://webpage/board/1234"
driver.get(url)

notice=driver.find_element_by_class_name("viewBox") 
bot=telegram.Bot('My token')
bot.send_message('My channel', 'notice')
```

I want to send the text in the viewbox as a message.
I got the text in the viewbox with selenium.
I made a telegram bot and also confirmed that it works.
How can I send the text as a telegram message?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is

```
bot.send_message('My channel', notice.text)
```

To find it you could type `dir(notice)` to see the element's attributes. And of course you can check the Selenium API documentation for the Element object.

Also, given that Element represents a web page object and it probably uses the same naming of javascript, you could open the dev console on Chrome (ctrl-shift-J) and type this:

```
// load Google Home first
a = document.getElementsByClassName('gb_g')[0]
a.text
> Gmail
```

As you probably know, the console is useful to be sure that the text you're looking for is actually in that `viewBox`

Comment: Thank you.
I got a hint from your answer.
Your answer was very helpful for me as a beginner.

Comment: @DongKyuShin glad to be of help :) Remember to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import telegram

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "http://webpage/board/1234"
driver.get(url)

notice=driver.find_element_by_class_name("viewBox")

bot=telegram.Bot('My token')
bot.send_message(chat_id="My chat id", text=notice.text)
```